# Allow VPS to connect through port 80/443

Tags: 16.04, security, firewall, ufw

If two vps servers exist and one runs livechat website and the other the main website... Can I use UFW to only allow connections to the livechat from the main website only?

I started by using the fllowing commands;

```
sudo ufw deny 80
sudo ufw deny 443
```

Then: (IP is example IP).

```
sudo ufw allow from 144.124.13.17 to any port 80
sudo ufw allow from 144.124.13.17 to any port 443
```

As I write this it occurs to me that the DENY rules above could be stopping the two IP allow rules above from working?

Is that so and if so how do I get this to work so that the main website is the only location allowed to connect to the livechat website?

Many thanks.

**ADDITION:** I removed the deny rules and so the firewall rules are now:

```
80                         ALLOW IN    144.124.13.17
443                        ALLOW IN    144.124.13.17
```

But the main server still cannot connect to ports 80/443 on the livechat server.

The main website vps normally connects to the livechat vps by using a domain name and the port isnt specified in the main website.

Any ideas greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: the vps's are hosted at ovh cloud

Comment: Is the cloud service provider's firewall enabled? If Yes, did you configure ovh firewall settings to allow for inbound traffic?

Comment: I don't fully understand linux systems but when I do a sudo ufw allow 80/443 the connection is made with no problem. I will look deeper into your question to see if I am missing something. Saying that, there is a "Configure firewall" setting in the cloud infrastructure for each vps but because connections are made to the servers via the internet when I use the sudo ufw allow 80/443 command I believed that the firewall was set to off?

Also I had a similar problem connecting two standard VPS's through specific ports/IP address just as the issue I am having now with previous ovh vps servers.

Comment: It seems the firewall on the cloud VPS's needs to first be created and so the answer to your question would be no the service providers firewall is not enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67779/discussion-between-legolas-and-hawk007).

Comment: sudo ufw status produces:

DOESN't Work
    80                         ALLOW       144.124.13.17
    443                        ALLOW       144.124.13.17

WORKS Fine:
    80                         ALLOW       anywhere
    443                        ALLOW       anywhere

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: BUMP! BUMP! BUMP!

Comment: You would have to run a `wire-shark` or similar trace on the server (when working fine vs when its getting blocked). Look at the records which differ, and figure out if there any IP addresses which are out of the allowed IPs.

Comment: sorry to ask but which server do I run wireshark on? the one connecting or the one being connected to? thanks. Or on my home workstation? not sure thanks.

Comment: Where you are modifying the firewall setting.